# How to set gnome-system-monitor to stop dynamically scaling the y-axis?

Tags: gnome, system-monitor

I have gnome-system-monitor open on my screen.  I'm looking at the 'Network' section.

In the last few minutes It has shown the following charts:

[image]
[image]
[image]

All of these only make sense after I check the axis - unlike the CPU and ram scores which have a defined maximum.  Given that I know a rough maximum for the upload and download speeds, is it possible for me to set the network chart to some fixed maximum so I can see what's happening at a glance?